# Android - RelativeLayout inflated as Button?

Tags: android, xml, inflate

I have a weird problem. While running my Android application, I receive Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
```

the code, where I try to get relativeLayout

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, null);
RelativeLayout btn = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

in xml, I've got this:

```
<RelativeLayout                
                android:id="@+id/my_button" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector"/>
```

While debugging, I've noticed that in v there is Button with mID equals to R.id.my_button.

Although, when I change id in xml and code to anything else, I receive NullPointerException.

Any ideas why this is happen ?

EDIT:
Maybe it will be helpful, if I add that in older version of that file there was Button, but was replaced with RelativeLayout. I'm using GIT. Project was cleaned many times and eclipse was restarted also.

Comment: By any chance, are you running two separate projects? one for 4+ and one for everything else.

Comment: Nope, it is one project. I've just tried to run it on different Androids.

Comment: Ah, my mistake! I got that ClassCastException even on lowe Androids. But why in xml it's RelativeLayout, and in View object it's Button? (I will update main post)

Comment: Do you have a <button> with the same id in your app? Your code gets a little confusing since your relative layout is called button.

Comment: Yes, I have Button with the same ID in my app, but it's on different layout. If I change this relative's ID and ID in findViewByID() method - it returns null.

Comment: Are you working in Eclipse? Because I work with ant and sometimes ids are not built properly. I have to clean the whole project and rebuild it from the scratch.

Comment: I work on Eclipse. I even run it on different Eclipse installations (on Windows and Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I've made one more layout file that I forgot about and it was for the same Activity byt different configuration. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the R.Java file and once recreated run the app it will work fine.

Comment: I've made clean on project. It deleted R.java file and recreated it. No progress withthis problem.

Comment: what context are you passing in the inflater?

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); (where context is an activity with different layout set as a content, but the button is not there. It looks like all elements are from one layout and that one button is from other.

Comment: ok. try inflating your view like this.
v = LayoutInflator.from(Activityname.this).inflate(your layout, null);
this may work worth giving a try.

Comment: Nothing. For some reason old, unchanged version of my home.xml is used :-\

Comment: copy the content of home.xml in a new xml and use it for further use seems to be a problem of adt

Comment: I did - application found other instance of the old xml file from don't know where. But it's different that last time and now no onClickListener from that layout works.