# Android - old xml layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-xml, android-build

I started with this question: [Android - RelativeLayout inflated as Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420187/android-relativelayout-inflated-as-button). It appeared that the problem was different.

So, why on modded Android application runs with old version of xml files (without last changes)? I use Eclipse to build application and use GIT.

What have I tried:

- refresh and clean on project.
- delete project folder and clone it again    (with removing it from
  Eclipse)
- running it on different Eclipse instances (on my laptop - Kubuntu and
  Windows, on friend's laptop - Ubuntu)

PS. Other xml files are from last commit. Only one is from far far past..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had separate folder for specific screen configuration with an old xml file. My mistake..